# How can I change JavaFx ComboBox text color

Tags: java, css, javafx, combobox, jfoenix

I tried every code on StackOverflow to change my combo box prompt text color to #989898, But it not changed and still in black color. Please if you have an idea about that it is very helpful to me. I'll add my CSS file below.

```
.combo-box
{
    -fx-font-size : 21px;
    -fx-font-family: 'Actor';
    -fx-text-fill : #989898;
    -fx-unfocus-color : #989898;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: #989898;
}

.jfx-combo-box
{
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: #989898;
}
```

Here is how its look like,
[Here you can see my combo box prompt text color changes from other text feilds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7Ypd.png)

Comment: for core combos, the prompt text fill is a css property of the combo's editor (see the javafx css spec to what's available) - so the selector should be `.combo-box .text-field`. Don't know if there's anything special in jfoenix

Answer (score 0):

One of these should work out:

```
comboBox.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #f0f0f0;" +
               "-fx-text-background-color: #f0f0f0;" +
               "-fx-text-inner-color: #f0f0f0;" +
               "-fx-font-weight: bold;" +
               "-fx-fill: #f0f0f0;");
```

Works for legacy ComboBox, JFoenix and MFX

Also, you can use CSS lookup:

```
    Node text = comboBox.lookup(".text");
    text.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #f0f0f0;" +
                                    "-fx-text-background-color: #f0f0f0;" +
                                    "-fx-text-inner-color: #f0f0f0;" +
                                    "-fx-font-weight: bold;" +
                                    "-fx-fill: #f0f0f0;");
    text.setFill(Color.rgb(240, 240, 240));
```